# "Gist" Vs "Purport"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

Please have a look on the dictionary definitions on the nouns "gist" and "purport" and let me know how they differ in meaning?

[**The gist:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/gist) 
The most important pieces of information about something, or **general information** without details.

[**Purport:**](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/purport) 
The **general meaning** of someone's words or actions.

It strikes me as if they are interchangeable in most cases. Here I have tried to bring up two examples in which I think using either of then will not make any change in the whole meaning:

**Example 1:**

> - I don't remember his exact words, but I can tell the the ....... of his words.

**Example 2:**

> - I didn't read it all, but the ....... of the letter was that he won't return.

I think we can use these two interchangeably in either case above.

Comment: The verb crops up occasionally but the noun is not used much these days.  If you do use it as a noun you should understand that it's about as pretentious as you can get without donning a powdered wig.

Comment: I'd say that ***noun*** sense of ***purport*** is [all but obsolete.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+purport%2Cthe+gist&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20purport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gist%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20purport%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20gist%3B%2Cc0) Just look at how far prevalence has dropped over the past couple of centuries! Also note that ***gist*** became more common over a century ago. The significance of using one or the other isn't about "meaning" - it's about ***prevalence changing over time.***

Comment: Thank you very much @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica; just could you please tell me what is the modern substitute for the obsolete "purport" these days?

Comment: I don't understand. You mean something ***other*** than ***gist**?* We can certainly refer to *the [broad]* [***thrust** of the argument*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thrust+of+the+argument%22) And there's always [*the **substance** of the argument*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22substance+of+the+argument%22)

Comment: Yes, definitely. I think there are so many other substitutes. But I am not quite sure which one is appropriate to be used instead of "gist"!

Answer (score 1):

Purport is considerably rarer than gist.

A gist is a brief summary.  The purport is the meaning or sense of a document.

Sometimes these are interchangable, but I'd understand "purport" to involve more interpretation.

> The gist of the letter was that your boss is getting on a plane tomorrow and he wants a meeting with you on Friday.
>
> I'll give you the purport of the letter: your boss is really angry!

But purport is rare and perhaps obselete.  "Purportedly" is sometimes seen in the wild, as a synonym of "allegedly"

Comment: Thank you very much @James K. Then I wonder what is the modern substitute for "purport" these days?